# Facebook integration setting section - where is it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-iframe

I 'm either stupid or the documentation needs updating. Please let me know :)

On this page https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150149060995844 says:

```
Change your "IFrame Size" to "Auto-resize"

On your application developer page, in the "Edit settings" section of your app,
in the "Facebook Integration" section, 
make sure that "IFrame Size" is set to "Auto-resize", 
NOT "Show scrollbars."
```

I can't find it on the developers site! :( Where on earth did they hide it? :o

Comment: That note is more than a year old... Things change quite rapidly on the Facebook platform. I suggest to you to go by the official documentation and not outdated tutorials...

Comment: Do you perhaps know where the equivalent setting to set iframe to auto-resize is? I can't find anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided is not official Facebook documentation.

For information on how to build a Canvas app (including a section on sizing information), please see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

This document provides information on how to make a fluid-sized Canvas app: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/